# How to eliminate {} brackets from message box

Tags: python, msgbox

I have script like this:

```
rp_1st_name = 1000
rp_last_name = 2000
rp_1st_val = 5555
rp_last_val = 6666
fdh = 200
dif = (rp_1st_val - rp_last_val) - fdh
teor = rp_1st_val - rp_last_val
```

m1='wysokosc reperu poczatkowego:',rp_1st_val,'mm \n'
m2='wysokosc reperu koncowego:',rp_last_val, 'mm \n'
m3='przwyzszenie na ciagu: \n'
m4='teoretyczne =',teor,'mm \n'
m5='obliczone = ',fdh,'mm \n'
m6='fdh =',dif,'mm \n'

from easygui import *
msgbox((m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6),"SUMMARY", ok_button="Exit")

How to make {} brackets were not displayed in message box?

Comment: Can you post what exactly the output you are getting is, so we know what "{}" you are talking about?

Comment: @Chris W. I would like to but I'm not trusted user and cannot upload images.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to think that

```
myvar = "String",value,"more string"
```

results in a string (`String 5 more string`) but it doesn't -
it gives you a tuple (`("String", 5, "more string")`)

Instead, try one of

```
myvar = "String " + str(value) + " more string"  # string concatenation
myvar = "String %d more string" % (value,)       # old-style string formatting
myvar = "String {0} more string".format(value)   # new-style string formatting
```